# unlink() como Apagar apenas um arquivo do ficheiro

Tags: php, html

Estou com dificuldade ao apagar um arquivo do ficheiro, quando passo um "GET", ele apaga todos os arquivos do ficheiro 
tenho que passar alguma variavel para identificar o nome do arquivo?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
        $pasta = 'uploads/photos/';
        if(is_dir($pasta)){
            $diretorio = dir($pasta);
            while($arquivo = $diretorio->read()){
                $arquivo = ''.$resphotos['photo'].''; 
                if(($arquivo!='.')&&($arquivo!='..')){
                    $id =  $arquivo = ''.$resphotos['id'].''; 
                    $del = DB::getConn()->prepare('DELETE FROM `photos` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1');
                    return $del->execute(array($id));  
                    unlink($pasta.$arquivo);
                    echo'<span> o arquivo foi apagado</span>';
                }
           }
       }
        $diretorio->close();
   }else{
    echo'a pasta nao existe';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Ta meio estranho esse código, tem um `return $del->execute()` depois um `unlink()` ?

Comment: de onde esta vindo o `$resphotos['id']`?

Comment: resphotos é da classe de album @Rafael Acioly é a funçao que faz select na tabela

Comment: @rray esse return é pra apagar o arquivo do BD sou iniciante em php, principalmente em PHPOO

Comment: o return vai _cancelar_ todas as linhas de código abaixo dele, ou seja ele sai da função

Comment: @rray eu removi o return , mas quando eu apago a foto nao apaga a foto certa, deleta a primeira foto carregada do album, e assim por diante

Answer (score 1):

A resposta a sua pergunta é sim! Você tem que indicar de alguma forma qual é o único arquivo que você quer apagar.

Seu código está apagando todos os arquivos porque está dentro de um loop while que percorre todos os arquivos dentro do diretório. Se você quer apagar apenas um arquivo, você não deveria usar `unlink()` dentro do `while`.

Acredito que você nem precisa de um loop while, já que você só quer apagar um único arquivo. Simplesmente passa-lo como parâmetro para `unlink()` já deveria resolver o seu problema.

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Comment: entao , @pauloequilibrio obrigado pela sua resposta, eu li um artigo sobre a funçao while e vi que while é uma funçao repititiva algo assim , imediatamente eu removi ele, tentei apagar uma foto , e o unlink nao apaga a img certa

Comment: Mas você está informando ao unlink() qual é a imagem certa?
Dá uma olhada aqui: [unlink](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php) no php.net

Comment: na variavel pasta eu concatrenei o id da foto ex $resphotos['photo']

Comment: OK, mas o nome do arquivo é apenas o id da foto? Não tem uma extensão tipo .jpg? O que deve ser informado a função unlik() é o nome do arquivo exatamente como visto pelo sistema de arquivos e não pelo banco de dados.

Comment: @pauloequilibrio o meu sistema de upload é compativel com todos os formatos (.bmp.jpeg.pjpeg.png.gif) como eu declaro esses formatos

Comment: @Php me dê um exemplo mais concreto do que você quer fazer, tipo me dê o nome de uma foto que você deseja apagar e as informações dela que estão armazenadas no seu banco de dados, para que eu possa lhe dar um exemplo de código que resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Usa var_dump() pra ver o que sai em suas variáveis assim vc debuga linha a linha se o unlinlk() nao ta excluindo é pq não ta achando o caminho ou arquivo correto

Comment: +1, a resposta foi direto ao problema. O loop está dando unlink em todas, não existe condição dizendo para apagar somente algumas. Na verdade o loop original tem uma complexidade desproporcional com a tarefa a ser realizada.